# Comparing weapons in Rage

Tags: rage

Is there a way to compare weapon stats and see how they stack up against each other in terms of damage, range, etc?

Especially when it comes to weapons from the same family like the double-barreled shotgun and the combat shotgun. Aside from the combat shotgun having a bigger magazine, is there any difference between them in terms of damage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no player viewable weapon stats in *RAGE*. :( You will have to go by the description on the weapon and the ammo.

In general: Feltrite good vs. armor, explosives good vs. most everything.

Everything else basically comes down to "What is your preferred play style?", As most weapons have several ammo types you can use guns in various fashions to suit any situation and style.

Answer (score 1):

Double-barreled Shotgun, as the name hints, fires two buckshot shells in one trigger pull, as opposed to the combat shotgun's single shell firepower, therefore making it twice as dangerous in close encounters. It's the same ammo type, though.

The main difference is in practical usage: DBS has to be reloaded after each shot, whereas the combat shotgun with the magazine upgrade has longer lasting firepower, making it better suited for crowd control.